# How to mount Vue3 app when root dom is replaced with app owned dom?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

In html file, there is a div for mount.

```
<div id="app" />
```

In main.js,

```
createApp(app).mount('#app');
```

After mounted, the real dom is

```
<div id="app" data-v-app>
  some app div
</div>
```

I want remove `<div id="app" data-v-app>`, so after mounted, only **some app div** in real page.
Who knows how to do it? Thank you.

Comment: once the page has loaded, `document.body.appendChild(document.getElementById('app').firstElementChild) && document.getElementById('app').remove()` if you must - expect breakages